# How to create a function to wait until a boolean value becomes true

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been creating a game using pygame, and I need a 'wait until' function for something in it to work. I know I could quite easily do this by just creating a while loop and breaking once the condition becomes true every time I need this functionality, but it would be far better if I actually had a function that I could use to do this. I wrote this function here and found that it didn't work:

```
def wait_until(condition):
    while True:
        Quit() #These three lines are required to allow for the program to continue running
        pygame.display.update()
        CLOCK.tick(FPS)
        if condition(): break
```

I believe this to be a result of when calling the function, the state of the condition in that moment is saved to the variable 'condition' as a Boolean. So it wouldn't do anything if it changed after that. For instance:

```
block = classes.sprite.Sprite(x = 50, y = 50)
wait_until(block.distance_to(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) <= 100)
```

would just be the same as passing `False` into the function if the mouse was further than 100 pixels away.

So what can I do to solve this problem, it really has stumped me and I've no idea what I could do to create a function that does what I'd like it to do.

Any help on the matter would be appriciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wait_until(lambda: block.distance_to(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) <= 100)
```

This creates a function that can be called as many times as needed, to evaluate your condition.

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem. I've never used lambda before so I wouldn't have known

Comment: @GeorgeWillcox Note that this behavior isn't tied to the lambda — you could equivalently write your condition in a function and pass the name of the function to `wait_until(...)`.  Either approach works because what you're effectively doing is enclosing the condition to be evaluated later by your function as opposed to evaluating the condition once and passing the result.